# Converter formato de data no echo do php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, echo

Boa tarde,

Minha database está guardando datas no seguinte formato "2017-04-19", não sei se tem como alterar os dados já cadastrados nela e o modo que os dados serão guardados, sendo assim optei por tratar a data no meu código php, o que não tenho tido sucesso, meu echo hoje está da seguinte forma:

```
   echo '<td>' . $row['data_chamada'] . '</td>';
```

Qual seria a sintaxe correta para transformar o formato da data para o usado aqui no Brasil(DD/MM/AAAA)?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar

```
    date_format($row['data_chamada'],"d/m/Y");
```

Comment: Eu até entendo a lógica envolvida, mas não consegui aplicar no meu código, como ficaria o echo nesse caso?

Comment: echo '<td>' . date_format($row['data_chamada'],"d/m/Y") . '</td>';

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu tentei mas ficou em branco o resultado, até achei que era eu que não estava sabendo aplicar.

Comment: Nesse caso o erro pode ocorre devido a $row['data_chamada'] não está em formato Date use DATE_FORMAT(campo,'%d-%m-%Y') na sua query sql usando assim você não precisa usar o formatado de data no echo do php exemplo: $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,,'%d-%m-%Y') FROM produtos" nesse caso seu codigo php vai ficar assim echo '<td>' . $row['data_chamada'] . '</td>';

Comment: Entendi, meu SELECT atual está abaixo, tem como adaptar ele ou preciso dar um jeito de fazer um novo?

$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM coleta_hc_2017 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100');

Comment: Você pode adaptar sua query colocando os campos a serem filtrados pelo SELECT usando o date_format para formata a Data, ou você pode pegar o resultado da query e transformar em um date  assim $date=date_create($row['data_chamada']);  e aplicar a primeira solução  
echo '<td>' . date_format($row['data_chamada'],"d/m/Y") . '</td>';